# How can I add the overall histogram in a grouped histogram plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ujg1e88e4s246n32qzt53/data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=apoo23jw9vg13mz2itizlplp2) which has multiple columns and one of them is a categorical variable. The categorical variable takes 3 values: 1, 2, 3. I want to create a plot in ggplot which will have the 3 histograms one below the other and then I want to add below the third histogram, the histogram in which we don't take into consideration the categorical variable. So far I have written the below code

```
#The name of the dataset is dataset.clust

dataset.clust$cluster = factor(dataset.clust$cluster)

library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2

dataset.clust$cluster = factor(dataset.clust$cluster)

hist_plot1 = ggplot(dataset.clust, aes(x = population, fill = cluster)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~ cluster, nrow = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Cluster")) +
  ggtitle("Grouped Histograms for population")

# Second Histogram
hist_plot2 = ggplot(dataset.clust, aes(x = population)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "yellow", color = "black")

# Combine histograms and arrange vertically
combined_plot = hist_plot1 / hist_plot2

print(combined_plot)
```

The above code gives me this[image]

Does anyone know how to combine these plots in one so that the four plots have the same x and y axis?

Comment: Please provide sample data for instance with `dput()`

Comment: @asd-tm I uploaded the dataset

Comment: A quick solution would be to create (a) your faceted plot, (b) an unfaceted plot and stack (or otherwise arrange) both with package {patchwork} or {cowplot}. See e.g. here: https://ggplot2-book.org/arranging-plots.html

Comment: @I_O I didn't find something helpful. Also, I edited my post in order to make more clear what I want to achieve. Can you provide some in order to fix my problem?

Comment: Well, {patchwork} did what you asked for, didn't it? The ocumentation also shows how to adjust the relative heights of stacked plots. Anyhow, see answer with ggplot-only solution, plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach would be to

- first add a (not yet used) level "A-C" to the factor "cluster"
- add a `geom_histogram` with its own dataset, which is the original data with cluster set to "A-C" for all observations

Example:

```
d <- data.frame(cluster = gl(3, 100, labels = c(LETTERS[1:3], 'A-C')),
                value = rnorm(300)
                )

d |>
ggplot(aes(value, fill = cluster)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    geom_histogram(data = d |> mutate(cluster = gl(1, 300, labels = c('A-C')))) +
    facet_wrap(~ cluster, ncol = 1) +
    scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c(LETTERS[1:3], 'A-C'),
                        name = 'redundant use\nof colour'
                        )
```

[image: combine subsets and whole dataset by manipulating the facetting factor]

Comment: I made the appropriate changes and it worked. Thank you so much!